# Inline Edit for Start and End DateTime for Event object?

Tags: event, inline

How to update duration field when we update Start time and Time of event using inline edit?
Note:- I am editing only Start date and End date using inline edit.

my requirement is like I want the start and end DateTime as inline editable in my table for the user. So the issue is like how to calculate again Duration..? Is it one time or updatable? Ok, and if change it in your customized table it's showing error while the update for DurationInMinutes...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to update the `DurationInMinutes` field if you're also updating the `EndDateTime` field. The system will populate it or update it automatically.

You just can't populate both unless the values match (i.e., the `DurationInMinutes` value is actually the difference in minutes between `StartDateTime` and `EndDateTime`).

From the [Event SOAP Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm):

> In versions 13.0 and later, this field (`DurationInMinutes`) is optional, depending on the following:
>
> If IsAllDayEvent is true, you can supply a value for either DurationInMinutes or EndDateTime. Supplying values in both fields is allowed if the values add up to the same amount of time. If both fields are null, the duration defaults to one day.
>
> If IsAllDayEvent is false, a value must be supplied for either DurationInMinutes or EndDateTime. Supplying values in both fields is allowed if the values add up to the same amount of time.

If you are making updates to an Event, you can either

- Not populate (not query) the `DurationInMinutes` field, in which case the system will autopopulate it;
- Null out the `DurationInMinutes` field (same result);
- Calculate the update to `DurationInMinutes` yourself.

Note that

```
Event e = [SELECT StartDateTime, EndDateTime, DurationInMinutes FROM Event LIMIT 1];

e.EndDateTime = e.EndDateTime.addMinutes(1);
update e;
```

results in an error, because we populate but do not update `DurationInMinutes`.

This works fine, because we don't query `DurationInMinutes`:

```
Event e = [SELECT StartDateTime, EndDateTime FROM Event LIMIT 1];
e.EndDateTime = e.EndDateTime.addMinutes(1);
update e;
```

as does this, where we set the field to `null`:

```
Event e = [SELECT StartDateTime, EndDateTime, DurationInMinutes FROM Event LIMIT 1];

e.EndDateTime = e.EndDateTime.addMinutes(1);
e.DurationInMInutes = null;

update e;
```

and this also works fine, because we update the field manually.

```
Event e = [SELECT StartDateTime, EndDateTime, DurationInMinutes FROM Event LIMIT 1];
e.EndDateTime = e.EndDateTime.addMinutes(1);
e.DurationInMinutes += 1;
update e;
```

So the upshot is you have no need to calculate the field yourself. Just don't query it in the first place, if you're not using it, or set it to `null` at the time you perform the `update` DML operation and the system will calculate it for you.

Comment: I have created list format in vf to show events and now i want to calculate duration when user changes StartTime and EndTime while update....

Comment: Hi @PranavJoshi, if you don't feel that my answer covers your question, would you please edit your question to clarify by including your code and describing why and how you are calculating the event duration? As I note above, the system will do this for you.

Comment: OK David my requirement is like I want start and end DateTime of is inline editable in my table. So the issue is like how to calculate again Duration its one time or updatable?

Comment: I have updated my answer to try to clarify.